# How to define a file to list all the global npm package that I'd like to install

Tags: npm

Is there such file that I can define all the node packages that I'd like to install globally? So that I don't have to remember to run

```
npm install -g eslint
npm install -g eslint-plugin-ramda
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Put them in your package.json: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

Comment: AFAIK, packages defined in package.json will be installed locally, not globally.